# css3 - how to make a delayed infinite animation with css, delayed each time it starts

Tags: css, css-animations

I am experimenting with css3 animation. I am working on three approaches:

Approach 1:

- to make a 3 step animation - rollin, shake, and roll out. I succesfully made this by:

  > -webkit-animation: rollIn 1s, shake 0.6s, rollOut 1s
  >
  > -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 5s, 8s;

Approach 2:

- to make a 2 step animation but the second step is infinite. That's easy if i set third element of each step to infinite:

  > -webkit-animation: rollIn 1s, shake 0.6s 3s infinite

Unfortunately that works in other way i'd expect. It rolls in immidiately for 1s, waits 3 seconds and start shaking infinitely. That's ok but each shake lasts 0.6s and next shake starts imidiately. My expectation is to [shake] [wait 3s] shake [wait 3s] shake [...] instead of [shake] [shake] [shake].

It works the same if I my animation has only one step:

Approach 3:

```
-webkit-animation: shake 0.6s 3s infinite
```

It also starts shaking after 3s (as intended) but later it shakes without any delays.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make infinite loop of css3 animation that honours a delay each time animation starts? In one step and multistep animations?

K.

PS: sorry for wrong highlighting, cant set it properly on first two code samples, i dont know why..
PS2: i could do it via javaascript - each time animation ends i could destroy appropriate div and create new animation from begining but i quess that is more complacated that it could be

Comment: You need to set the delays inside the keyframes, using 2 frames with the same values

Comment: thx.. i read about it but instead i prefer some delays with javascript. shame it works that way